# How to replicate a composite POST in SOAP-UI

Tags: rest, soapui

I'm trying to test an endpoint that will accept a certain request. It takes 5 minutes to go through the process of firing off the request, so I'd like to replicate it in SOAP-UI. I'm not sure how to get the request to look like the following.

```
Host: somedomain.net
User-Agent: Jakarta; Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
--7ZRj4zj5nzTkWtBlwkO5Y4Il-En_uTGP2enCIMn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="companyId"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

985
--7ZRj4zj5nzTkWtBlwkO5Y4Il-En_uTGP2enCIMn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inputFormData"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response>Response XML Data</response>
--7ZRj4zj5nzTkWtBlwkO5Y4Il-En_uTGP2enCIMn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="completedAgreement"; filename="48ce7fa4079790440a964815a744d232.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PK
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not recreate in SOAP-UI but I was able to create a simple html form to get the job done.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/api/receiver" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            Company Id:<br />
            <input type="text" value="725" name="companyId" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Input Form Data:<br />
            <textarea name="inputFormData" rows="10" cols="50">
            </textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            Completed Agreement:<br />
            <input type="file" name="completedAgreement" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The most important part was setting the `enctype` in the `form` tag to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`